# Copy data from one worksheet to another and remove row from old work sheet

Tags: vba, excel

This is the code that I have written, but basically I want to copy data from one worksheet to another with a condition e.g :"closed", and by doing that the row in the old worksheet must be deleted. I was able to copy a row to another sheet but it was copying the row 4 times, I can't figure out why. Can you please look at this code? I'm not so advanced with VBA.

```
Sub macro_1()
Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long
lr = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For r = lr To 2 Step -1
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 2 Step 1

If Range("G" & r).Value = "closed" Then
    Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
    lr2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End If
    If (Cells(i, "G").Value) = "closed" Then    'Cells (i, "A").EntireRow.ClearContents ' USE THIS TO CLEAR CONTENTS BUT NOT DELETE ROW
    Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next i

Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second loop, that is what is causing your problems.

Also it is good practice to always declare the parents of your objects.  The code below declares the two sheets, then every range is qualified to the proper sheet.  This way if for some reason the focus is lost to the active sheet, errors are not encountered.

It also makes it easier to rename the sheets.  The name only needs to be fixed in one place not many.

```
Sub macro_1()

Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For r = lr To 2 Step -1
    lr2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If ws1.Range("G" & r).value = "closed" Then
        ws1.Rows(r).copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & lr2)
        ws1.Cells(r, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```